# How do use Sass in Docusaurus v2?

Tags: sass, docusaurus

I followed the instructions to use Sass in my Docusaurus v2 project, but I get the following error when I run `yarn start`:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'docusaurus-plugin-sass'
```

My config file is straight out of the box:

```
module.exports = {
  title: '...',
  tagline: '...',
  url: '...',
  baseUrl: '/',
  favicon: 'img/favicon.ico',
  organizationName: '...', // Usually your GitHub org/user name.
  projectName: '...', // Usually your repo name.
  themeConfig: {
    navbar: {...},
    footer: {...},
  },
  presets: [
    [
      '@docusaurus/preset-classic',
      {
        docs: {...},
        blog: {...},
        theme: {
          customCss: require.resolve('./src/scss/index.scss'),
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
  plugins: ['docusaurus-plugin-sass'],
};
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things to check

- Did you add `docusaurus-plugin-sass` to your `package.json`?
- If you're using alpha.56, take note of the following change - https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/releases/tag/v2.0.0-alpha.56

> If you refer to modules (plugins) in your config file in a string form, you will need to replace them with `require.resolve` calls, for example:

```
- plugins: ['@docusaurus/plugin-google-analytics']
+ plugins: [require.resolve('@docusaurus/plugin-google-analytics')]
```

Comment: Adding `require.resolve('[PACKAGE NAME]')` worked for me. Thank you!